# Pass object on other component Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm beginner in **Vue.js** and I'm kinda confused how to pass an object in other component...

My problem is I have two component file named **Component A** and **Component B.**
**Component A** has three buttons and **Component B** is supposed to fetch array.

What I want to do is whenever I clicked in **component A**, **component B** will fetch the data

I tried to pass it via parameters but I don't get the output I want, please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: create JSFiddle to show what you're doing. It is not easy to get what you want to do from what you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a custom event. You can use a vue instance as the event bus:

```
const bus = new Vue()
```

ComponentA will emit an event when the button is clicked.

```
onClick () {
  bus.$emit('onAClick')
}
```

ComponentB listens on that event and call the API when the event happens.

```
bus.$on('onAClick', () => {
  this.contentFromAPI = fetchAPI()
})
```

here is a simple example: http://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/VPBBeZ?editors=1010